# Handling Errors with RESTSerializer

Tags: ember.js, error-handling, ember-data

Using ember and ember-data 2.6 versions, I'm trying to get error handling working but running into issues. I'm using the `RESTSerializer` and I'm sending the following payload to my server:

```
{
    "brand": {
        "name": null,
        "description": null,
    }
}]
```

Since `name` cannot be null, this is what I'm sending back as my response:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "code": null,
        "detail": "may not be null",
        "status": null,
        "title": null,
        "source": {
            "pointer": "brand/name",
            "parameter": null
        }
    }]
}
```

In my route, I am doing the following in the save promise on failure:

```
console.log(savedBrand.get('isValid')); // logs false
console.log(savedBrand.get('errors').toArray()); // logs [ ]
```

There doesn't seem to be a lot of detailed documentation on how this all works so I'm using [this article](http://thejsguy.com/2016/01/09/handling-errors-with-ember-data.html) as a starting point. I'm unsure as to why `toArray()` returns an empty array instead of my error that I'm returning in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though I'm not passing in the data per the json-api, the `pointer` still had to be set as if I were:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "code": null,
        "detail": "may not be null",
        "status": null,
        "title": null,
        "source": {
            "pointer": "/data/attributes/name",
            "parameter": null
        }
    }]
}
```